# using try, except inside a function in Python

Tags: python, try-except

Using try, except inside a function in the following code producing a correct result.

```
def try_function():
    try:
        hrs = float(raw_input("Enter Hours: "))
        rate = float(raw_input("Enter Rate: "))
        return hrs * rate
    except:
        print "Values are non numeric"
        quit()

pay = try_function()
print pay
```

I got the following result:

```
Enter Hours: 20
Enter Rate: 10
200.0
```

While if i change the code to the following i get not result:

```
def try_function():
    try:
        hrs = float(raw_input("Enter Hours: "))
        rate = float(raw_input("Enter Rate: "))
    except:
        print "Values are non numeric"
        quit()
    return hrs * rate

pay = try_function()
print pay
```

Here what i get :

```
Enter Hours: 20
Enter Rate: 10
```

I don't know why i am not getting the value 200, and which way is better the first or the second?

Thank you.

Comment: Works as expected for me in python 2.7.3 on debian linux. which version of python are you using?

Comment: Works fine at http://repl.it/languages/Python.

Comment: i am using Python 2.7, and Windows Xp

Comment: note that using a bare `except:` is usually a very bad idea, as it will also catch special exceptions like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `StopIteration`.  you almost always want `except Exception:`, or in this case, a more specific type like `except ValueError:`.

Comment: I agree with you and i thank you for the advice, but i have spent really considerable time trying to understand why i am getting a result in the first case while not result in the second one.

Comment: I get 200 in the second case

Comment: What happens if you change the ````except```` to ````except ValueError```` and have your ````return```` inside an ````else```` block?

Comment: I tried to run it using IDLE and it worked in fine in both cases, but running it using Notepad++ didn't produce 200 in the second case.

Comment: are IDLE and notepad++ both pointing at the same version of Python? Also can you just run from the command prompt?

Comment: The only version i have is Python 2.7.3

Comment: if the OP were using python3 , the code would not run at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I mean Python 2.7.3 or 2.6 etc...

Comment: @nettux why would python 2.6 not work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham both case work as expected for me in Python 2.7.3 under debian linux and on http://repl.it/languages/Python so this could be an issue limited to a particular version/platform combo.

Comment: I have increased the line indent by extra tab , and it produced 200 in both cases now, but if it was indentation error the code should not run at all, or am i wrong ?

Comment: I would expect to see an indentation error. Are you using exclusively tabs for indentation? I believe Python interprets tabs to be equal to 8 spaces.

Comment: i used tabs to indent and i thought that if there is indentation error it will appear when i run the code, but what confused me was that the code worked without errors but without 200 in the second code while in the first code no any problem and the output is 200

Comment: always use spaces to indent!  python and your editor were probably disagreeing on how wide a tab is.  and you can run `python -tt` to get syntax errors in the case of ambiguous indentation

Comment: Thank you very much Eevee, very useful advice, and thank you all guys for your comments, i appreciate that from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have an issue with mixing of tabs and spaces for indentation. Check if your indentation is consistent.

For example, if some lines are indented with tabs, and some with spaces, then visually the indentation might look correct, but Python could interpret the indentation differently than the way it appears in your editor.

You can try running Python with the `-t` option, which will give you a warning if there is a mix of tabs & spaces indentation. E.g.:

```
python -t myprogram.py
```